# All the values from database on page load in dropdownlist to be bind and default value to be selected which can be chaged after updation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a dropdownlist which is bind with database, having some values.

It is properly retrieving all the values from the database, but it needs to be updated as well on button click and after updating it should select that value, my stored procedure is working perfectly

but I don't know how to set the updated value as the default value of the dropdownlist.

I am using C#, ASP.NET 4.0 and sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

On pageload use a select query

 then check the row count

example :

```
 if (dtCheck.Rows.Count > 0)<br>
 {
   if (!IsPostBack)<br>
   {
       ddlAnswers.SelectedValue = dtCheck.Rows[0] ["columnname"].ToString()                  
   }

}
```

Note; `if(!IsPostBack`) is used so that if you update the database using client side it will not retrieve the selected value in the drop down during page load

Answer (score 0):

Store the selected dropdown selected value in Viewstate before button click event happens.

```
  ViewState["selectedValue"] = ddlAnswers.SelectedValue;
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (ViewState["selectedValue"] !=null)
       {
        ddlAnswers.SelectedValue = ViewState["selectedValue"].ToString()
       }
    }
```

Please try this. This way you can reselect the preselected value.